# Dynamic select columns with list in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, arraylist

I Having and Movie Class  with Id, MovieName, Disc, RelDate

```
List<Movie> MovieData = db.Movies.ToList();

return Json(MovieData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

this will return below data

```
[
 {
  Id: 1,
  MovieName: "JungleBook",
  Desc: "Good Movie",
  ReleDate: "/Date(1460917800000)/"
 },
 {
  Id: 2,
  MovieName: "Fan",
  Desc: "Lets See movie-1",
  ReleDate: "/Date(1460831400000)/"
 },
 {
  Id: 3,
  MovieName: "Jadu",
  Desc: "must see",
  ReleDate: "/Date(1460658600000)/"
 }
]
```

But I want return data based on selected columns and 
eg when I pass Id, MovieName then it will give me below result(Id and MovieName is dynamic condition)

```
[
 {
   Id: 1,
   MovieName: "JungleBook"       
 }
]
```

Based on column condition it will return me array list with all data with specified columns.

Comment: What have you tried? You're just telling us what you want to do. Filtering a collection is one of the basics of programming. I would recommend reading up on a tutorial, first.

Comment: I Just tried to remove column from list but it is in stuck to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with LINQ to select columns in your table and filter results :

```
var selectedData = db.Movies.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => new {Id = x.Id, MovieName = x.MovieName}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to chose columns dynamically you can use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)